# Angular 2 Radio Button Validation with ngModel

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms

[Angular 2's documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) tells about the form validation. But only for input fields type text. My question is for Radio Buttons.

Here is HTML:

```
<input type="radio" required name='gender' value='Male' [(ngModel)]='gender'>Male
<input type="radio" required name='gender' value='Female' [(ngModel)]='gender'>Female
<button type='button' [disabled]="??">Next<button>
```

How to set disabled property to true if user hasn't selected any value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With template driven forms you can expose your model to a local variable and query the errors object.

```
<form #f="ngForm">
   <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="gender" required #genderControl="ngModel"> Male
   <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="gender" required> Female
   <button [disabled]="genderControl.errors">Next</button>
</form>


export class App {
  gender = null; 
}
```

Comment: Could you add a plunker please? Your solution is not working for me

Answer (score 10):

Since you didn't say which Forms Module (Reactive or Template driven) you were using here's a reactive forms version:

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="radioTest">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value='Male' formControlName="gender" [(ngModel)]='gender'>Male
  <input type="radio" name='gender' value='Female' formControlName="gender" [(ngModel)]='gender'>Female
  <button type="button" [disabled]="radioTest.controls['gender'].invalid">Gender Button</button>
</form>
```

**component code**

```
radioTest: FormGroup;
gender;
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.name = 'Angular2'
  this.radioTest = fb.group({
    gender: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

Here's a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mWhYtc2nf8hSHFbLWlEx?p=preview

Comment: But you see he using ngModel.

Comment: `ngModel` itself is available in Reactive Forms as well as Template Driven. A dead giveaway for it being strictly template would be `#inputVariable="ngModel"` or marking `ngControl` somewhere on the input. Instead, the exact code he posted is open to interpretation. I know using `ngModel` bindings on reactive forms is generally discouraged in the documentation but it is available.

Comment: Your plunker is broken atm. It's years later, but you might want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the other answers are trying to attach variables to the radio elements, when the radios already become part of the `ngForm` therefore doing a `myForm.valid` would work.

Here's mine:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="gender" required> Male
  <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="gender" required> Female
  <button [disabled]="f.valid">Next</button>
</form>
```

Just a `f.valid` should do.

Comment: Because, most likely, you have other inputs in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Validate mat-radio-group using Angular2

```
<form [formGroup]="answerTypeFormGroup">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>first name</ng-template>
        <mat-radio-group formControlName="answerTypeCtrl" required>
        <mat-radio-button value="option_1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="option_2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="option_3">Option 3</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</form>
// if answerTypeFormGroup is not valid show some error
<div *ngIf="!answerTypeFormGroup.valid" >some error</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, while this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.