# how to enable submit button onchange radio button

Tags: html, angular, forms, typescript

Below is the code for my edit form

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="saveUser()" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="block">Gender</label>
    <div class="clip-radio radio-primary">
      <input type="radio" id="wz-female" [(ngModel)]="item.profile.gender" formControlName="gender" value="female">
      <label for="wz-female">Female</label>
      <input type="radio" id="wz-male" [(ngModel)]="item.profile.gender" formControlName="gender" value="male">
      <label for="wz-male">Male</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="checkForm(editForm)" class="btn btn-primary btn-o next-step btn-wide pull-right" (click)="saveUser()">Save</button>
</form>
```

how to validate this radio button, in order to enable submit button when I change the radio button from male to female or vice versa, as it is my edit form.

Comment: yes, I have done validations for all other input fields but struck at this radio button validation, so seeking some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html Code.

```
<form [formGroup]="radioTest">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value='Male' formControlName="gender" [(ngModel)]='gender'>Male
  <input type="radio" name='gender' value='Female' formControlName="gender" [(ngModel)]='gender'>Female
  <button type="button" [disabled]="radioTest.controls['gender'].invalid">Gender Button</button>
</form>
```

component

```
radioTest: FormGroup;
gender;
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.name = 'Angular2'
  this.radioTest = fb.group({
    gender: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

check this plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/mWhYtc2nf8hSHFbLWlEx?p=preview

more refernece [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144161/angular-2-radio-button-validation-with-ngmodel)

Comment: it very near but the thing is, I already have male radio button checked,  so now when I change the radio button from male to female it should enable the submit button. (consider an edit form, I want to edit info inside edit form)

Comment: so what you want now? the by default male should be checked?

Comment: when I navigate to edit form, my radio button has the male as checked and  the submit button will be disabled initially, but when I change male button to female, submit button should be enabled

Comment: it will do the same thing just checked your male radio button as checked and it will work as it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Simply store the default value in a variable and put

[disabled]="defaultValue == currentModelValue"

Condition on button