# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am using angular 7 and validating a form in it. Validation is working perfect for text input but for radio i am getting this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
```

Below is my input radio code

```
<input type="radio" name="radioAns" [(ngModel)]="opt.checked" #radioAnsRef="ngModel" required value="{{opt.id}}">
```

`radioAnsRef` is undefined but only in radio input when i am trying to validate the field by `radioAnsRef.valid`

For input text result of checking valid is true or false but for radio its undefined

> I have seen so many similar questions but all are with solution of defining `#radioAnsRef` in html but my issue is different and happening only in input radio and input checkbox

Comment: where does `valid` enters on the code above?

Comment: when i am trying to validate it with `radioAnsRef.valid`

Comment: now.. with the edit I can see.

Comment: From the few nightmares I remember about angular's form validation, the component ref should be the same as the tag name, hence `#radioAnsRef="ngModel"` should rather be `#radioAns="ngModel"`

Comment: @briosheje tried this also but not working

Comment: @GauravAggarwal can you please provide a plunkr or stackblitz or whatever? it's quite a problem without a (not) working example.

Comment: No problem here [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cgafch-so)

Comment: @rmjoia Thanks for creating one but when i was creating stackblitz example i came to know that its not working with me because in my code i am replicating it with `ngFor` and inside `ngfor` only its not working.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal so did you find a solution?

Comment: @rmjoia not just found out that i was this is the problem now looking for a solution

Comment: @GauravAggarwal is it something like this you're looking for? [Angular 2 Radio Button Validation with ngModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144161/angular-2-radio-button-validation-with-ngmodel) (I updated my stackblitz with that solution)

Comment: @rmjoia https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2451 this is my issue